# How to skip to the next video with the "Next" button in Sony DVD Architect

Tags: video, dvd

I inserted 10 media in a DVD project, each video has its scene/chapter markers at the beginning and 3 minutes before the end. While I preview as disc, the "Next" button works fine when skipping from beginning to the end, but it somehow doesn't skip from video_1's end to video_2's beginning when I pressed the "Next" button. It seems to be only skipping chapters in a single video, and doesn't skip to the next video. 
One more thing, it can start video_2 when video_1 reached the end, because I set the end action of video_1 navigate to video_2's beginning. So it sucks because I need to wait until it ends instead of skipping to the next video :(

Could this problem be solved? Or is there any other way to do that? Thanks a lot.